# Running two application on the same database in CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have two application, one is J2EE (Spring-MVC based) application the other one is a J2SE application. Is it possible for me to run both application on CloudFoundry with the same database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, multiple applications can bind to (an therefore use) the same service (database).  It is up to the service to implement multi-tenancy.

From http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/using/services/managing-services.html#bind ...

Binding a service to your application adds credentials for the service instance to the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable. In most cases these credentials are unique to the binding; another app bound to the same service instance would receive different credentials. You may need to restart your application for it to recognize the change.

Comment: Dead link. Live one is this: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/managing-services.html#bind